# which http methods allowed in "*" when enabling CORS in web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, cors

I have implemented CORS in web API by using Cors library.

```
   [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

and in webapi config file

```
       config.EnableCors();
```

I called api using POST method, still I was getting error in console i:e No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Then I changed

```
      [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
```

To

```
     [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS")]
```

Then its started working, my question why it doesn't work with allowed methods   using "*"

Comment: This is .net core right?

Comment: no its .net framework

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The wildcard for `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` is not yet supported by all browsers.

- Chromium-based browsers should support it ([issue 615313](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=615313))
- Firefox does not yet support it ([bug 1309358](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1309358))
- IE probably doesn't support it and Edge possibly does not support it yet. Edge is moving to the Chromium engine in the future, so they'll support it at some point.

Browser support is also tracked by MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Methods#Compatibility_notes), so future readers may want to check that too in case this answer becomes outdated.