# Ajax POST call blocked by CORS from ASP NET Web API - Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api, cors

### Problem Summary:

I have two web projects that are hosted with different domains.  When making ajax call to my Web API project I get the following:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at '' from origin '' has been blocked by CORS
>   policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control
>   check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
>   requested resource.

---

### First Project - Web API

My first project, which is ASP NET Web API (.Net Framework 4.8)

I enabled CORS globally for everyone just to make sure the tests pass correctly.
In my `WebApiConfig` file, I have the following line.

`config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*"));`

With `using System.Web.Http.Cors;` above.

My method has nothing special like attributes since we enabled CORS globally.

```cs
[RoutePrefix("api/Test")]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [Route("RequestConnection")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult RequestConnection(MasterOnRequestInputModel inputModel)
    {
        ...some code logic here...
    }
}
```

---

### Second Project - JavaScript with AJAX request

My second projects want to call the mentioned method above in the Web API.

My ajax call looks in the following way:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: myUrl,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        'Body': body,
        'Head': head,
        'Width': width,
        'Height': height
    },
    success: screencastControllerPostSuccess
});
```

In Chrome the request looks as follow:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

---

Edit:

### Answer

If you guys did, exactly what is written above, you should have absolutely no problems with CORS.

My problem was with the [WAF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application_firewall) our company is using. The WAF was denying my request due to it being a potential attack. And this is because I was sending HTML elements in the request body. Together with my system administrator colleagues, we fixed the issue.

So the interesting part is, that after my request is denied from the WAF it returns an error as if the problem is with CORS. That is because indeed the request is cross-domain, but the WAF generic response after denying a request doesn't have the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

Comment: does the "cross origin" server handle "OPTIONS" request? That's what pre-flight is

Comment: Yes, it does. I was thinking I am missing something in the ASP Net Controller. Or maybe some headers in the ajax?

Comment: Clearly, since the OPTIONS response headers are missing the required Access-Control headers

Comment: `In Chrome the request looks as follow:` - what do the **response** headers look like - request headers are not the issue

Comment: It doesn't have any. `Failed to load response data`

Comment: so your server is not handling `OPTIONS` request method

Comment: see this : - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56577232/which-http-methods-allowed-in-when-enabling-cors-in-web-api

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the WAF of [www.asp-waf.com](http://www.asp-waf.com), you will find it quite easy to work with also finding issues like that are easy as you just register with the OnGuardAction event and you can see what and why it would be blocked by debugging it or sending it to the log.

we do this by using the base class FireWallBase like this

```
public class MyFireWall : FireWallBase
{
    private readonly ILogger<MyFireWall> _logger;
    private bool _agreeWithFirewall = true;

    public MyFireWall(
        //enable accessing AppConfig
        IConfiguration configuration

        //allow DI to provide interfaces to base class
        , ILoggerFactory? loggerFactory = null, IMemoryCache? memoryCache = null
        , IIncidentDatabase? incidentDatabase = null, IWhoisRepository? whoisRepository = null, ISubscriptionsRepository? subscriptions = null
        , IEmailReportDesination? emailReportDesination = null, IDatabaseReportDestination? databaseReportDestination = null
        , ILoggerReportDesination? loggerReportDestination = null, IFireWallDiskLoggerDestination? diskLoggerDestination = null
        , IEventLogReporting? eventLogReporting = null, IGeoFactory? geoFactory = null, ILatLongRepository? latLongRepository = null
        , IResetRepository? resetRepository = null)
        : base(loggerFactory, memoryCache, incidentDatabase, whoisRepository, subscriptions, emailReportDesination, databaseReportDestination
              , loggerReportDestination, diskLoggerDestination, eventLogReporting, geoFactory, latLongRepository, resetRepository)
    {
        var section = configuration.GetSection("FireWall");
        if (section.Exists())
        {
            _isReccommendOnly = section.GetValue<bool>("AgreeWithFirewall");
        }
        base.Trigger_OnFireWallCreated(this);
        OnIncident += MyFireWall_OnIncident;
        OnGuardAction += MyFireWall_OnGuardAction;
        OnUserTypeChange += MyFireWall_OnUserTypeChange;
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<MyFireWall>();
    }


    private void MyFireWall_OnUserTypeChange(object? sender, Walter.Web.FireWall.EventArguments.UserTypeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        _logger?.LogCritical("{oldType} : {newType}\n   {route}\n   Rules:\n   {data}"
            , e.OriginalType
            , e.NewType
            , e.Rout
            , string.Join("\n   ", e.Rules)
            );

        //allow the change
        e.Allow = true;

        if (e.OriginalType.HasFlag(UserTypes.IsSearchEngine) && e.NewType.HasFlag(UserTypes.IsMalicious))
        {
            //remove the malicious flag from search engines to not prevent search engines from 
            //indexing the site
            e.NewType &= ~UserTypes.IsMalicious;
        }
    }

    private void MyFireWall_OnGuardAction(object? sender, Walter.Web.FireWall.EventArguments.GuardActionEventArgs e)
    {
        _logger?.LogCritical("{Method} {page} : {route}\n   {action}:{RuleNr}\n   Reasons:{Reason}\n   {data}"
            , e.Page.Method
            , e.Page.OriginalUrl.AbsolutePath
            , e.Page.FireWallRoute
            , e.Action
            , string.Join("\n   ", e.Page.PageViolationStack.Select(s => s.ToString()))
            );

        //allow the firewall to block requests
        e.Allow = _agreeWithFirewall;
    }

    private void MyFireWall_OnIncident(object? sender, Walter.Web.FireWall.EventArguments.FireWallIncidentEventArgs e)
    {
        _logger?.LogCritical("{Method} {page} : {route}\n   {rule}:{RuleNr}\n   Reasons:{Reason}\n   {data}"
            , e.Page.Method
            , e.Page.OriginalUrl.AbsolutePath
            , e.Page.FireWallRoute
            , e.StackEntry.Rule
            , e.StackEntry.RuleNr
            , e.StackEntry.Reason
            , string.Join("\n   ", e.Data.Select(s => $"{s.Key}:{s.Value}"))
            );
        //allow the firewall to raise incidents
        e.Allow = _agreeWithFirewall;
    }
}
```

We enable the firewall like everything else in .net web applications via dependency injection. I can enable my own firewall class by using it like so:

```
services.AddFireWall<MyFireWall>("Token", "Key", new Uri(Configuration["domainUri"], UriKind.Absolute), options =>{
         //add your options here
       });
```

In the options, you can configure CORS under options.Rules.Headers but you can do lots more than that.

The firewall is in my NuGet package [Walter.Web.FireWall.*](https://www.nuget.org/profiles/ASP-WAF) There are lot's of add-ons like geography as well as reporting to SMTP timed using a timespan you you can get emails every day and not get flodded with mails when a user got blocked.

Comment: have a look at https://www.asp-waf.com/download/ASP-WAF-FireWall-Getting-Started.pdf